# Same command in Runtime Exec works only if passed statically inside code

Tags: java, cmd, exec

The command written statically in the code works:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

String cmdUpdt = "D:\\Root\\Draft_Update.exe -se_file=\""F:\\TCC\\Stage\\DC\\Ude34edacx34c1f34\\M08521.dft\"" -input_file=F:\\TCC\\Stage\\DC\\Ude34edacx34c1f34\\result\\SEAttributeFile_M08521.txt -log_file=F:\\TCC\\Stage\\DC\\Ude34edacx34c1f34\\result\\SEAttributeFile_M08521.log"
rt.exec(cmdUpdt);
```

The same command obtained dynamically doesn't work:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

String cmdUpdt = Constants.moduleFolder+Constants.DraftUpdateEXE + " -se_file=\""+seFile+"\" -input_file="+inputFile+" -log_file="+logFile;

rt.exec(cmdUpdt);
```

Comment: What happens if you compare cmd and cmdUpdt?  cmd.equals(cmdUpdt)?

Comment: Same cmd, the first one is obtained by copying the log produced during the second way (dynamic string)

Comment: And when you print them out are they the same? Or use `String.equals` to check, just to be certain.

Comment: Completely the same

Comment: What message you get as an error?

Comment: Any message, simply the program Draft_Update.exe doesn't start, I figure out this because the target file is not updated after the process and so after the log

Comment: And what happens in your first 'cmdUpdt' declaration if you change it to:  string cmdUpdt = " .... (the same) ..." + "  ";  You are not changing the sentence (only add spaces).  Does it work?

Comment: Adding spaces it still works

Comment: And if you split the first 'cmdUpdt' into two strings?  something link this:  String cmdUpdt = "D:\\Root\\Draft_Update.exe -se_file=\"F:\\TCC\\Stage\\DC\\Ude34edacx34c1f34\\M08521.dft\" -inp" + "ut_file=F:\\TCC\\Stage\\DC\\Ude34edacx34c1f34\\result\\SEAttributeFile_M08521.txt -log_file=F:\\TCC\\Stage\\DC\\Ude34edacx34c1f34\\result\\SEAttributeFile_M08521.log";

Comment: In this case didn't work.. (?) any idea why ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144842/discussion-between-noomak-and-jose-luis).

Comment: I don't understand why fails.  I have not Java installed, I can't try nothing.  I hope someone else could help you :-(